# Tell sed to make changes but those starting with a specific string in 8th to last line

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

Here again with another problem with `sed`.

As the title says, I want `sed` to change lines starting at the 8th line to the end, but only lines which start with `<b>`.

I have  code all ready and just wanted to append the argument to change lines starting with `<b>`.

Example of code `sed -e '8,$ { s/\./\0<\/b>/ }' > "$file"_new`

Example input:

```
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">COAT. how are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">MONEY.Where are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">FOOD.what are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">FOOD.what are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">CAR.which are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">CAR.which are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">QUALITY.When are you.
```

Example output:

```
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">COAT.</b>how are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">MONEY.</b>Where are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">FOOD.what are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">FOOD.</b>what are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">CAR.</b>which are you.
<font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">CAR.which are you.
<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">QUALITY.</b>When are you.
```

These lines are situated from 8th line to end. I don't want any kind of change in 1-7th line.

Comment: Is that example code not working?

Comment: Ya it working but all files are not as they suppose to be so i have to indicate the line starting with `<b>` also

Comment: What is that which you want to append?

Comment: the argument to change only the lines starting `<b>`

Comment: Is AU the best place for this question?

Comment: @blujay Well, i am not sure of your question but as i use ubuntu as a single installation and have a habit to add ubuntu/linux in search query for each and every thing related to ubuntu and computer in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fit your requirements

```
cat TestSed.txt 

Line 1
Line 2
<b>Line 3.
Line 4
Line 5
<b>Line 6.
Line 7
Line 8
<b>Line 9.
Line 10.
<b>Line 11
<b>Line 12.

sed '8~1s/^<b>.*\.$/\0<\/b>/' < TestSed.txt

Line 1
Line 2
<b>Line 3.
Line 4
Line 5
<b>Line 6.
Line 7
Line 8
<b>Line 9.</b>
Line 10.
<b>Line 11
<b>Line 12.</b>
```

The `sed` here, does substitution `s/Regular Expression To Search/Replacement Text/` and it applies this regual expression `^<b>.*\.$` over each and every line read and when it matches, it replaces it with `\0<\/b>`. Here \0 refers to the text which matched the regular expression `^<b>.*\.$`.

`^<b>` will match lines starting with `<b>`

`.*` will match zero or more characters. So,

`^<b>.*` will match lines which are starting with `<b>` and has zero or more characters after that.

`^<b>.*\.$` will match lines which are starting with `<b>` and has zero or more characters after that and ends with `.`

`\0` in the replacement text will give the text which matched the regular expression. In our case, its the whole line.

`\.`, `\/` the backslashes are used here to escape `.` and `/`. They both have special meaning in regular expressions. We want to treat them as strings here. So we are escaping them.

`8~1` tells sed to start applying the substitution from line number 8 and apply it after every 1 line, which means rest of the file. If you look at the example, it doesnt do any change on Line 3 and Line 6 though they match the regular expression.

**EDIT:**

```
sed '8~1s/^<b>[^\.]*\./\0<\/b>/' < TestSed.txt
```

This will match the text till the first `.`

`[^\.]` will match any character except `.`

`[^\.]*` will match any character except `.`, zero or more times.

Rest of the explanations are the same.

Comment: Thanks again for your helpful input, but as i have mentioned above in the examples that i want the `</b>` only after the first `.` and not any where else in the line. But the above comman is appending `</b>` after the last `.`. I also tried to remove `$` after the `.` in the command i.e. `sed '8~1s/^<b>.*\.$/\0<\/b>/' < TestSed.txt` to `sed '8~1s/^<b>.*\./\0<\/b>/' < TestSed.txt` only to find out it does the same job.

Comment: And special thanks for the complete explanation of your command, it's such an valuable info for me :)

Comment: Thanks :) Even I learnt a lot about `sed` to answer your question.

Comment: Hello thefortheye, there is a problem i got to know now, though the command is working fine with the test file but it is not doing anything to the original files i want to change and those files are huge to even paste here, any way i can send you an original file to review if you have a bit of time?

Comment: You can paste the line for which you expect sed to apply the changes, but it actually isnt

Comment: Even a simple command like `sed -e 's/æ/a/g'` is not working with original filess where as working fine with test files. :(

Comment: but more complex command like `sed -r 's_<font color="#800000">&nbsp;<a name="([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)"></a>|\[([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)\] \[<a href="#top">[A-Za-z. ]+</a>\]__g' | sed -re 's_</font><font color="#008080">_<b><font color="#000000">_g'` working just fine, I am totally out of any clue.

Comment: the lines are too long to post so i am pasting just the primary part of line from an original file `<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">MIND. <br></font></b>Forgetfuln....******* too long` to be `<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">MIND.</b> <br></font></b>Forgetfuln....******`

Comment: You can view the whole file [here](http://pastebin.ca/2374209)

Comment: As a temporary workaround i am using `sed -e '/<b><font color="#000000">./ { s/\./\0<\/b>/ }'` n it's working fine. Regards.